# angular dropdown multiselect to connect data between three dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

I have three multiselect dropdowns:-

```
<label>Dropdown One</label>
<div ng-model="a.dp1" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="multiSelectArray" selected-model="dropDownOne" extra-settings="multiSelectSettings">
</div>

<label>Dropdown Two</label>
<div ng-model="a.dp2" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="multiSelectArray" selected-model="dropDownTwo" extra-settings="multiSelectSettings">
</div>


<label>Dropdown Three</label>
<div ng-model="a.dp3" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="multiSelectArray" selected-model="dropDownThree" extra-settings="multiSelectSettings">
</div>
```

Directive Code:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('page', page);

    page.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout', 'ApiServices'];

    function page($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.a = { };
                $scope.dropDownOne = [];
                $scope.dropDownTwo = [];
                $scope.dropDownThree = [];
                $scope.multiSelectArray = [{
                    name: "Ayan"
                }, {
                    name: "Rita"
                }, {
                    name: "Mohit"
                }, {
                    name: "Shittal"
                }, {
                    name: "Jayant"
                }, {
                    name: "Sachin"
                }, {
                    name: "Tina"
                }, {
                    name: "Babita"
                }, {
                    name: "Priya"
                }];
                $scope.multiSelectSettings = {
                    smartButtonMaxItems: 11,
                    scrollable: true,
                    displayProp: "name",
                    idProp: "name",
                    externalIdProp: "name"
                };
            },
            templateUrl: 'js/folder/system/page.html'
        };
    }

})();
```

What I am trying to do here is when I select particular options from 'Dropdown One' the same options got selected in 'Dropdown Two' and 'Dropdown Three' and get disabled so that users can't unselect them. Also, the users can select more options in 'Dropdown Two' and 'Dropdown Three' if they want, but the options from 'Dropdown One' should be checked already and disabled.
I am trying to disable the options using 'disabled' attribute but not able to for selected options. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: is it related to bootstrap??

Comment: no, it is not related to bootstrap

Comment: You should try to do your work yourself.. Instead of asking someone to do it for you

Comment: cool !! enjoy :)

Comment: can you create a plunker?